Supporting 16kb page size in an Android app not using NDK
We are preparing ourselves to support Android 15 and according to official docs,

Android supports devices that are configured to use a page size of 16 KB (16 KB devices). If your app uses any NDK libraries, either directly or indirectly through an SDK, then you will need to rebuild your app for it to work on these 16 KB devices.

A dedicated page explain necessary steps to support 16 KB devices but honestly I'm confused. We don't use NDK and only few .so files are present in the final APK by the third party libraries (Chief among them com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android). Should we build these libraries our self? How can I find that these third party .so files don't use 4KB page size?
Since I'm not familiar with native development in Android, simple explanations would be appreciated.
We use AGP 8.3 and default settings for uncompressed shared libraries

Generally you wait for your libraries to support it themselves, then just do a rebuild to pick up those changes.  If the library you use isn't in active development and supporting these changes, then you should really think about finding a more active replacement.

It seems like the library you use has stopped development.
https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid -> last commit 6 years ago.
Most likely the library will not be updated.
Your options are

Wait for the maintainer to update the project
Wait for somebody else to update the project
Do it yourself
Switch to an actively maintained pdf library

You can test your app in an 16kb emulator.
The Android team described the process here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/page-sizes#test
